# Max value 3D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, max

We have a 3D array (671, 9066, 2):

- 671 IdUser (bloc)
- For each 671 users we have 9066 (rows) movies and proba associated (2 columns)

Example of two columns for 1 user:

```
Proba                Idmovie
[  6.93933334e-02,   1.00000000e+00],
[  8.50563031e-02,   2.00000000e+00],
....
[  2.95071098e-02,   3.00000000e+00]
```

We need the maximum proba (here 8.50563031e-02) and the value of the second column associated (here 2.00000000e+00). This for each 671 users!

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for sure there is a smarter way but my approach would be:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.random((3,3,2))
print(x)


for user in x:
    maximum = np.max(user[:,0])
    index = np.where(user[:,0]==maximum)

    print(user[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

The most compact way in numpy is probably something like this:

```
x[range(x.shape[0]),np.argmax(x, axis=1)[:,0],:]
```

**Explanation:**

```
np.argmax(x, axis=1)
```

*returns the indices of the maximum values along the second ("movies") axis*

```
np.argmax(x, axis=1)[:,0]
```

*reduces this to the first column only since we only need the indices for the maximum proba*

Using these indices as an index array, we simply retrieve the respective proba/idmovie tuple for each user. The result is an array of shape (671,2) with the maximum proba and associated movie id for each user.